# boilerplateless tests

Tags: python, import

I have testing files wirtten in Python : test1.py test2.py...
Before executing any of them I need to initialize them with a file called initialize.py that takes arguments.

The testing files must stay as light and easy to write as they can be.

I want to create a script that:

1. Takes input arguments
2. Start the initialize.py file with those arguments
3. Start the test file using the variables created by initialize.py

I thought about a few ways:

- Import the two files : it doesn't work because with import you can use the return argument on your main script but you can't give input argument
- Transform both files into functions : it's not an issue with initialize.py but as I said I want to keep the test file to be as easy and light as possible so if I can avoid that it's better.
- The perfect solution would be to simply "copy" the code from initialize and put it in the beggining of the test file (or the opposite). May be create a temporary file containing both code but i don't think it very clean.

To sum up : it's as if I had 100 files that starts with the same 25 lines and I want to put those 25 lines in one file and import them each time.

An other way to see things is 3 files:

```
#File1.py
var1 = sys.argv(1)

#File2.py
var2 = var1+"second"

#File3.py
var3 = var1+var2+"third"
print var3
```

I want to start ./File1.py first
And get "first second thrid"

I succeed with

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys

import subprocess
source_content = "#! /usr/bin/python\n"+"import sys\n"

sourcefile = "file2.py"
txt_file = open(sourcefile)
source_content += txt_file.read()

sourcefile = "file3.py"
txt_file = open(sourcefile)
source_content += txt_file.read()

destinationfile = "Copyfile2.py"
target = open (destinationfile, 'w')
target.write(source_content)

target.close()

chmodFile = "chmod 777 "+destinationfile
chmod = subprocess.Popen(chmodFile, shell=True)
chmod.wait()
arguments = str("./"+destinationfile+" ")
arguments += " ".join(map(str,sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]))
startTest = subprocess.Popen(arguments, shell=True)
startTest.wait()
```

But I had to delete the "#! /usr/bin/python" from test2 and test and rename var1 to sys.arg[1] on thoses same files.
And I don't think it's a nice solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you use the unittest module?

```
import unittest

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def initialisation_script_stuff(blah,etc):
        foo

    def setUp(self):
        common_setup_stuff()

    def tearDown(self):
        whatever
```

Now you can just inherit from BaseTest in each of your test files.

```
from moo import BaseTest

class CoolTest(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        BaseTest.setUp(self)
        args = BaseTest.initialisation_script_stuff()
        do_stuff(args)

    def testNumberOne(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)
```

Alternatively if you want to stay away from standard unit testing methods...

Assuming the directory structure:

```
all_tests\
    __init__.py
    some_tests\
        __init__.py
        test1.py
        test2.py
    other _tests\
        __init__.py
        etc
```

Some naming conventions:

- each test py file has a function named `run` that runs the test
- each test py file has a name starting with 'test'
- each of the test grouping folders has a name ending in '_tests'

Make a single script called run_tests.py (or something like that...)

```
def run_tests():
    import os
    import importlib
    import re
    dTests = {}
    lFolders = [s for s in os.listdir('all_tests') if re.match('.*_tests$',s)]
    for sFolder in lFolders:
        sFolderPath = os.path.join('all_tests',sFolder)
        lTestFileNames = [s for s in os.listdir(sFolderPath) if re.match('^test.*py$',s)]
        for sFileName in lTestFileNames:        
            sSubPath = '{0}.{1}'.format(sFolder,sFileName.split('.')[0])
            dTests[sSubPath] = importlib.import_module('all_tests.{0}'.format(sSubPath))
    #now you have all the tests...
    for k in dTests:
        stuff = initialisation_stuff()
        test_result = dTests[k].run(stuff)
        do_whatever_you_want(test_result)             

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_tests()
```

Now you need absolutely no boiler plate code in your test files. Just so long as you follow the formula

Comment: It's a good solution but it's still a lot of stuff to write on each test file. The fact that it's test files is not important. It's as if I had 100 files that starts with the same 25 lines and I want to put those 25 lines in one file and import them each time.

Comment: @user2707890: There is obviously more to this... so you have bunch of test files (test1.py, test2.py etc) and an initialiser function common to all tests. Here are the fuzzy bits: how are you grouping your tests? one per test file? And how are you planning to run your tests? All at once with the same initialiser function arguments? All at once with initialiser arguments specified on a per test or per test file basis? One at a time?

Comment: The test are grouped in folders but I want to be able to run them one by one or by folder.So I was willing to create two scripts but I think that if i can create the first one (one test a a time) i can create the other one easily so i am focusing on that. Yes it's one test per file. (a test file is about 150 lines) and for the "full test" it's the same arguments for all the tests.

Comment: Why did the name of my question changed to "boilerplateless tests"...?

Comment: What was it before? Maybe this is more accurate? It's good for things to be named according to what they are about. Sometimes better titles emerge as requirements do, vague titles don't help anyone

Comment: How is it realted to "boilerplateless tests"?

Comment: boilerplate code is code you repeat over and over again. boilerplateless => lack of boilerplate.

Comment: Ok I never heard that before, thank you